# Is it possible to call rasa default events like rasa.core.events.AllSlotsReset from external API?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

I need to perform custom action from my server when all slots are filled for a specific intent.
and once the action is performed I want to reset the rasa state.
is there a way to do it from endpoint, which can be called from my server after performing custom action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forms](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/forms) for filling a set list of required slots. And to reset all the slots, I would actually suggest returning that event from the custom action directly, by doing a `return [AllSlotsReset()]` from your actions [run method](https://rasa.com/docs/action-server/sdk-actions).

You can also add events to the tracker through an API call via the tracker events [endpoint](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/pages/http-api#operation/addConversationTrackerEvents). But if it's dependent on a custom action being executed, then the simplest way is the way I described above.